# combinatio of scatter and pie plot in python

Tags: python, scatter-plot, pie-chart

Suppose that I have sample data like this:

```
#Sample Data
df=pd.DataFrame ({'x':[1,1,2,2],'y':[2,3,2,3],'Share':[0.834437,0.165562,0.966749,0.033250]})
```

'x' represents customer number, 'y' represents store id, and 'Share' shows the percentage of customer purchases from one store compared to all stores. it means that the sum of Share For each Customer must be near 1.

on the other hand, each store has 2 products: A and B, that customers can buy, and each product, has the percentage of customer purchase too.

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'y':[2,2,3,3,2,2,3,3],'product'=[A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B],'ProdShare':[0.863095,0.136904,0.940000,0.060000,0.842494,0.157505,0.925233,0.074766]}
```

For example customer number 1, purchased from store number 2,0.834437 times that he purchase. he buy product A 0.863095 times and buy B 0.136904 time (0.863095+0.136904~1)

now I want to show this in the plot

as you see this is `scatter_pie` chart each circle show the share percentage of a store and inside each circle, the red color shows the share percentage of A, and yellow show the share percentage of B.
how can I have this chart in python?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to use subplots.

This is what I got:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

labels = ["A", "B"]

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2, 
    specs=[[{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}], [{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}]],
    subplot_titles=['Subtitle 1', 'Subtitle 2', 'Subtitle 3', 'Subtitle 4']
)

A_percents = [0.863095, 0.94, 0.842494, 0.925233]
B_percents = [0.136904, 0.06, 0.157505, 0.074766]
sizes = [0.834437,0.165562,0.966749,0.033250]
rows = [1, 1, 2, 2]
columns = [1, 2, 1, 2]

for i in range(4):
    
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Pie(
            labels=labels, 
            values=[A_percents[i]*sizes[i], B_percents[i]*sizes[i]], 
            scalegroup='one',
            name="Name"
        ), 
        row=rows[i], col=columns[i]
    )

fig.update_layout(title_text='Title', height=950, width=950)
fig.show()
```

How it works: plots in the same scalegroup are represented with an area proportional to their total size.

To arrange plots in a different order, change `rows = [1, 1, 2, 2]` and `columns = [1, 2, 1, 2]` to whatever you need.